# How to change color of bounding box in insertObjectAnnotation method

Tags: matlab

```
frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame,'rectangle',bboxes,labels,'TextBoxOpacity',0.9,'FontSize',18);
```

The following picture shows the output from the MATLAB code. The bounding box is of yellow color. Is it possible to change this color, and how?

[image]

Comment: I guess that you can simply add a new parameter 'color'. For example: `frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame,'rectangle',bboxes,labels,'TextBoxOpacity',0.9,'FontSize',18,'Color','red');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the Vision System Toolbox, but according to the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertobjectannotation.html), you can insert a [named pair](http://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertobjectannotation.html#input_argument_namevalue_color), like this:

```
'Color', 'white'
```

Try the following:

```
frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame,'rectangle',bboxes,labels,'TextBoxOpacity',0.9,'FontSize',18,'Color', 'white');
```

Supported color strings are: 'blue', 'green', 'cyan', 'red', 'magenta', 'black', and 'white'

Comment: You can also use RGB vector: `myfunction(...,...,'Color',[1,0,1])`